# TypeError while instanciating generic Object

Tags: typescript, generics, typeerror, instantiation

I´m getting a `TypeError: type is not a constructor` while trying to transform API-Data to Frontend-Dtos.

The Transform-Method looks like this:

```
transform<T>(entities: any[]) {
    const tableDtos = new Array<T>();
    for (const entity of entities) {
      const dto: T = this.factory.createEntity(entity);
      tableDtos.push(dto);
    }
    return tableDtos;
  }
```

My Factory like this:

```
export class Factory {
  create<T>(type: (new () => T)): T {
    return new type();
  }
}
```

I took the solution from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics). What am I missing here?

DTO

```
import { Entity} from 'src/models/api/Entity';

export class EntityTableEntry {

  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(entity: Entity) {
    this.id = entity.ID;
    this.name = entity.Name;
  }
}
```

Entity

```
export interface Cost {
  ID: number;
  Name: string;
  Description: string;
  Value: number;
}
```

The reason why I want to have an generic method is, that I would need to re-write the transform method for each API-Call, which is a complete mess!

Comment: what does`entities` contain ? The way you are using it it should contain classes (So you would be calling something like (`transform([Class1, Class2])`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `entities` contains the data for the objects you want to create. As such it will not be callable with `new`. You want to pass in the actual class you want to create (maybe assign the data to the new instance):

```
class xx {
  factory: Factory = new Factory();
  transform<T>(type: (new () => T), entities: any[]) {
    const tableDtos = new Array<T>();
    for (const entity of entities) {
      const dto: T = this.factory.createEntity(type, entity);
      tableDtos.push(dto);
    }
    return tableDtos;
  }
}

class Factory {
  createEntity<T>(type: (new () => T), data: any): T {
    var r = new type();
    Object.assign(r, data) // guessing a decent implementation here 
    return r;
  }
}

class DataClass { a!: number }

var r = new xx().transform(DataClass, [{ a: 1 }]);
console.log(r);
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAevQN4ChrQGZmAFwPYCcBPALmgDEs8joBeaAOwFMB3cygwgCgEoBuVaNnxh6EdAQC2AHgAqAPk7ZCAB0alOTVj1pzoM7gBpojetgCW5xhFIjCAbQC63JALTBco7ILAAjEIwARPBg6TWgAQXxhQlkFPlcMAmhOd09jUwtCaFx0dPNLCGcUNBLoVIgvABM8UhlaQQALMwgAOkwcDhbgfEYwbEYAUQylRRVGIxN8wnjStGxffyDcVuUAVwgGzmrcGZKAXwSe7FX8em8-QOD+NAOD5FBIGAoO6mKynr7B4Zj5UdV1MLaGi6fRGSp9MA2ejTWouUoANzA+GgyNCLEEYx41xKAHkfAArRg4FqPMwAc3onHwYIhzgA9HToGTVlYIGZ6GToGBoJUiZNoGYJMp-BJJn0zB5oA1GD1oIdGMdTijsbdkPdwFBoAEIQBhDUwRBcgCEpHoqwkPhl0DuiORqIY6PgPBaQhEYkknG18z1jyMdkNkOgAEZrU5+OVcP4WiBcGSqXwgA)

Comment: Thank you - I think this is the direction to solve my problem. If I use this code it gives me the following error: ```Argument of type "typeof dtoClass" is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => dtoClass' ``` I´m not using the method in the Dto-Class - I am using it in an Angular-Componente-Class to map the incoming Data to mor frontend-friendly dtos. I will put an example class of an Entity and a Dto into the question.

Comment: @FlixRo the only issue is that `EntityTableEntry` has an argument with parameters, you can update the signature of the constructor to include the parameter : `new (p: any) => T`

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for the question but where exactly should the paramters go? If I put it into the create like this ```createEntity<T>(type: (new (p: any) => T), data: any)``` the error continous to show.

Comment: Nevermind - I forgot to put it in ```transform``` aswell. Reduced the createEntity to ```static createEntity<T>(type: (new (p: any) => T), data: any): T {
    return new type(data);
  }``` Thank you so much for clearing this up! :)